# What is the correct way to say “and the last is“?

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german, swiss-standard-german

I am talking about a number sequence and before the last number, I want to say:

> and the last is ...

as, for example, in *"1, 2, 3 ... and the last is 100"*.

When I use a translator, it shows:

> *der* letzte ist ...

or

> *das* letze ist ...

Since numbers are feminine, I would have said:

> *die* letzte ist ...

What should be the correct form to say this? And why don't we make *letzte* a noun form *Letzte*, since we are using an article here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The expression *the last is*, or in German *der/ die/ das letzte ist*, is an [elliptical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) expression, in which the noun was omitted. Therefore, the question is: The last *what*? And depending on the noun that you have in mind, the article changes.

For example:

> - the last (value) is
>
>    *der* letzte (*Wert*) ist
> - the last (number) is
>
>    *die* letzte (*Zahl*) ist
> - the last (item) is
>
>    *das* letzte (*Element*) ist

The ellipsis is also the reason why [*letzte*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/letzte) is not capitalized here; it is an adjective, which modifies the (omitted) noun.

Comment: Even if it is an ellipse, most people would probably think of "Zahl" in this context, so "die" would be preferable. Especially since OP itself says "numbers".

Comment: @mtwde, I disagree. As someone who studied mathematics, I would think of *Element (einer Folge)*. Actually, I would say: *"... und **das** letzte (**Element**) ist **die Zahl 100**.“*

Comment: Most people would simply say something like "... und zuletzt ..." or "... am Ende ..." or nothing at all ("...,98,99,100").

Comment: nobody would say "...und zuletzt" it sounds unnatural.

Comment: @user3700562: Echt jetzt :-) ? 'Zuletzt' wäre das Erste das mir einfiele. Really ? It'll be my first choice. I believe it works in English, too "... and last (but not least) ..."

Answer (score 6):

That can be said in different ways. I would prefer "1, 2, 3... and *finally* 100".

> 1, 2, 3 ... und zum Schluss 100

But you can also say:

> 1, 2, 3 … und abschließend 100

or

> 1, 2, 3 … und als letztes die Zahl 100

Comment: Genau, most idiomatic "zum Schluß", "am Ende", "zuletzt".

Answer (score 3):

The grammatical gender of an article, a pronoun or some other parts of speech **always** depends on the gender of a noun.

Always!

This means: at all times, without any exception.

Learn this: If there is no noun, it still depends on the gender of a noun.

So, it depends on the noun the speaker has in their mind. Very often the context provides such a noun, so not only the speaker, but also the listeners know which noun is meant, and so everybody also knows which gender is the correct gender.

In other words: All three genders are possible. It simply depends on the context. Are you counting male participants of a sports competition? Are you counting books on a shelf? Are you counting jam jars in your stock?

Without this information, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Evasion: Answer with an adverbial expression that doesn't need to comply. For example "Und, zu guter Letzt, ..."

Answer (score 2):

Hängt vom Kontext ab. Der Mathematiker würde "1, 2, 3, ... bis 100." sagen.

Comment: Alle x für die gilt x Element N aus dem geschlossenen Intervall von 1 bis 100. Sorry, kann kein Latex ... :-)

Comment: MathJax klappt hier leider nicht.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens in an reasonably informal context, or even a university lecture, the most likely phrasing would be something like

> 1 2 3 und so weiter, *[notable pause]* ...100.

> Einzwodrei, ded-ded-ded, 100.

> Alles von 1 bis 100.

> Ein, zwo, drei vierfünfsechsimablblblbl , 100.

> 1, 2, 3, bis am Schluss dann 100.

In writing, to be precise I'd go with

> Alle ganzen Zahlen von 1 bis einschließlich 100.

Comment: +1 für *ded-ded-ded* Denn nun weiß ich, dass das, was ich zu hören glaubte, keine Einbildung war:)

Answer (score 0):

A rather common ending would be

> und zu guter Letzt 100

Which is sort of an expanded version of "und zuletzt 100" which scans better.